# Force Chrome to check if a $.ajax call has finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

Good afternoon guys -

Is there a well known way to check if a `$.ajax` call has finished?

-- FOR INSTANCE --

Let's say I'm using a `$.ajax` call to load in a large number of leaflet polygons from a .geojson file (asynchronously as a layer group). Under normal circumstances, this happens almost immediately - but the user has elected to load a large job this time around. The user has assumed that the set of polygons has been loaded and attempts to do something with this group of layers prematurely - only to find that nothing happens (the layer group doesn't actually exist yet in the browser).

My intuition (I'm new to web development) is to have some sort of global flag that's set for the dependent algorithm to check. We would set the flag prior to loading the layers, and then change it to some other value in the `.done({})` section of the `$.ajax` call.

**-- UPDATE --**

I've reworked the code to allow users to choose whether or not they wish to retry the request, and also force the browser to wait some time before retrying the request.

However, I've also found the the issue seems to be with Chrome. Firefox appears to be able to handle the $.ajax.always callback as soon as it finishes (in other words, the $.ajax.always callback will interrupt the regular flow of javascript).

**Chrome appears to block the $.ajax.always callback and only lets it execute after all other javascript has finished running (no interrupt).**

This particular question stemmed from a debug case that automated user input from within a loop - and since Chrome doesn't call the $.ajax.always callback until the current process is complete, the process isn't marked as completed.

Example Code:

```
procBox = []; // Global scope, stands for Process Box

function loadPolygons() {
    procBox["loadPolygons"] = "running";

    $.ajax({
        // ajax things here 

    }).done(function() {
         procBox["loadPolygons"] = "done";
    }).fail(function() {
         // failure stuff here
    });
}

function dependentFunction() {
    if procBox["loadPolygons"] === "done") {
        // The meat of the function (dependentFunction things here)

    } else {
        // Backup case that allows the browser to retry the request
        /* --
         * If this fires, the server is still trying to process the 
         * ajax request. The user will be prompted to retry the request,
         * and upon agreement, the function will be called again after
         * 1 second passes.
         */

        var msg = "Oops! It looks like we're still fetching your "
                + "polygons from the server. Press OK to retry.";

        if (confirm(msg)) {
            setTimeout(dependentFunction, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

This approach seems to work well in Firefox - the `alert()` stops JavaScript execution and gives it a chance for the `.done({})` callback to occur. But for some reason, the while loop never allows the `.done({})` callback to complete in Chrome!

Does anyone know of a better approach for this than using flags or `async: false`?
I appreciate any answers and knowledge out there!

Comment: Don't block javascript indefinitely. Use a timeout or interval.

Comment: Read more on `Promise`s.  You're going to need wrap your head around them a bit more.

Comment: Maybe you're seeking for `.always(...)`. It's like `finnaly` of `try/catch` but for jquery's `done/fail`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/ You can see the docs here

Comment: Use beforeSend to show something to user or block parts of the UI manually while ajax is in progress. Seems like you are looking at the situation all backwards

Comment: Thanks tkausl - 
I built in a timeout for the actual code - e.g. if the while loop executes more than 15 times, it alerts the user to try again, and forces the user to re-call the dependent function. 

I'm trying to run a benchmark script on this code. Do you know of a way to force chrome to stop and check if a callback has been made from the .done({}) section of the $.ajax call? As is, chrome isn't updating the "procBox", even if the callback occurred while waiting for the Alert box to be closed.

Comment: I recently started looking into promises (they looked promising ಠ_ಠ) but hadn't implemented them yet. I'll check out the .always(...) callbacks notgiorgi - and thanks for the suggestion zero298.

Comment: `setTimeout(dependentFunction(), 1000);` should be `setTimeout(dependentFunction, 1000);`.

Comment: You're right - typo carrying it over from the actual code. Thanks for the update tcooc.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to do :
as already sugegsted you can use
since you use jQuery, you can use custom events https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/:

```
$(document).on("myajax:done", function(){ dependentFunction();})
$.ajax({...}).done(function(){
    $(document).trigger("myajax:done")
});
```

or even global ajax events
https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

but really consider why not to do something like

```
procBox = {onLoadPolygons:dependentFunction}; // Global scope

function loadPolygons() {
    $.ajax({
        // ajax things here 

    }).done(function() {
         procBox["onLoadPolygons"]();
    }).fail(function() {
         // failure stuff here
    });
}

function dependentFunction() {
        alert("Please wait for the polygons to load");
     dependentFunctionThings();

}
function dependentFunctionThings(){
    // Do dependent function things...
}
```

UPD:
if you ensist on your structure, and still want to use blocking function
use **setInterval** to perform check

```
function dependentFunction() {
    var h = setInterval(function() {
         if (procBox["loadPolygons"] == "done") { 
             clearInterval(h);
            // Do dependent function things...
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Or wrap it up into a Promise (http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises)

```
function dependentFunction() {
   (new Promise(function(resolve) {
      var h = setInterval(function(){
         if (procBox["loadPolygons"] == "done") { 
             clearInterval(h);resolve(); 
         }

      }, 100);
   })).then(function(){
       // Do dependent function things...
   });
}
```

But I still believe that something wrong in your structure

Comment: I think I'm missing something here - the code works well on firefox already (just not on Chrome). 

I need to make javascript pause for a moment to check if the asynchronous algorithm has completed before the user tries to edit the data again. (I don't want the function to automatically be called after the $.ajax completes - I just want to check that it isn't still processing when the 'dependentFunction()' is called by the user.)

Comment: @Dylan, I don't know where and how your "dependentFunction" called, but I'm surprised if it works in Ff, as soon as you run infinit loop your CPU should be shoked, you can wrap up your check into setTimeout(()=>{if(ajaxEnd==1) doYourThings}, 100), but your "while" should be replaced with "if", how many alerts you receive after condition will be true?

Comment: The alert() stops the javascript execution in firefox - and the callbacks still fire behind the scenes. 9 times out of 10 the $.ajax completes before you can click [ ok ] on the alert(), and it exits the loop on the first or second try.

However, this same approach doesn't work in chrome (leads me to believe there's something fundamentally wrong with this approach). I've checked out wrapping it in a setTimeout() function, and this seems -like- it would work from here, but I haven't implemented it yet.

Comment: I've updated the answer with solution that saves your structure, but really, you have some preparations, and some user-triggered action, so I'd just create this two events and on each of them would check if another event occurred, and then launch "dependent function things"

Comment: Coming from other languages, I feel that there _has_ to be something wrong with the structure I'm using. I looked into some of your suggestions and added the setTimeout function to ensure it works. (Furthermore, I've found that chrome seems to handle the $.ajax callbacks differently than Firefox - leading to the issue of this working wonderfully in Firefox, but getting stuck in Chrome.)

Comment: setInterval is better in your case, since delay of ajax-answer is hard to predict, and what language you came from?, just curious )

Comment: Java, C, Python & VB mostly. When something stops working like this between browsers it makes me think that I'm fundamentally doing something wrong (hahah)

Comment: After some experimentation, I've found that there really is a difference between Firefox and Chrome in this situation. Surprisingly, Firefox allows callbacks to occur *when a modal dialogue box is displayed*. Chrome doesn't allow callbacks to occur (since js is single threaded). I'm not sure why firefox lets this happen.

Answer (score -1):

From the docs :

```
.ajaxComplete()
```

Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery triggers the ajaxComplete event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxComplete() method are executed at this time.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

Comment: Interesting - I think I'm following. Could I create some kind of queue of function calls that are fired once the $.ajax completes? 

Right now, the approach is to try to find a way to check if the $.ajax function is still processing (with the procBox[] flag) when the 'dependentFunction' is called when a user clicks on a button.

Comment: In fact ajaxSuccess() would be probably better since it is called only when ajax request is done with HTTP 200 response. ajaxComplete() executes always when the ajax request is finished. Anyway, just put your post ajax functions in the .ajaxComplete() /  .ajaxSuccess()function and play with it. Jquery documentation and examples are pretty explicit.

Comment: It isn't so much that I want something to happen as soon as the ajax request completes - I just need to be able to check that it _has_ completed. It totally works in the Firefox just fine! (I updated the topic above to explain what seems to be wrong with running this through Chrome. Perhaps there's something that I'm missing with promises)